# How can I clone a protected HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, clone

I have a copy protected HDD.

It works perfectly in a kiosk but when I try to clone it using clonezilla, ghost or any other sector to sector copiers I get i/o errors...
I think they've ruined some sectors just to block the copy (just like in sweet old times of amiga disks).

Back in time I used a software called diskdupe to copy also the error on the disk...

Any info about an application that blindly raw clones an hd even if it has errors (or a workaround)?

Comment: HD = High Definition, HDD = Hard Drive

Comment: @typoking: In the days of "standard definition", HD meant "hard disk". (HDD is "hard disk drive".)

Comment: @grawity even in the time of standard definition, I have never seen hard drives referred to (correctly) as HD.  It seems more appropriate to use HD for high definition and HDD for hard drive (or the extended version "hard disk drive" as you said).

Comment: @typoknig: Regardless, we all understand what the OP means, which is all that matters, right?

Comment: @typoknig: I've seen “HD” for hard disk far more often than “HDD”. There's certainly nothing incorrect about it. “HD” is ambiguous, like just about every two-letter abbreviation. In this context, it clearly doesn't mean “high definition” or “high density” or “Heidelberg” or “hemodialysis” or …

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hd thinks HD is both (4 types of) High-Definition, *and* Hard Drive, while it feels http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdd is both High Definition Display and Hard Disk Drive. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: My point is that if you are talking to computer guys these days HDD is more appropriate than HD when referring to a Hard Drive.

Comment: Indeed since my SSD is faster than your HDD ;-)

Comment: Never got the chance, since 1996, to see this amount of attention and effort on a single term of a topic.
Stackoverflow, Serverfault and his brothers are the new limit of knowledge I can imagine.
God bless you all and our hdd.

ps
Hd as hard disk is actually a LOT older than HD as high definition which has just a few years.
Anyhow I do understand the need of distinguishing lately and I'll be more accurate in my next questions: thank you all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) or [`dd_rescue`](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/), which are designed precisely to copy all that's salvageable off a disk with errors. Both are available on many repair live CDs, for example [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/).

Comment: Great point, my friend!
I'll try and come back with news :)